# ShellExecuteEx wierd behavior in Windows 8

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, windows-8

The code below for file with no-extension brings up a dialog shown below listing applications that can be used to open the file. This behavior is seen only from Windows-8. And the applications listed in the dialog are taken from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes*\OpenWithList. Is there anyway to suppress this dialog and get a behavior similar to old platforms?

-Karthik

```
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO shinfo;
unsigned long  mask = SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI;
memset(&shinfo,0,sizeof(shinfo));
shinfo.cbSize = sizeof(shinfo);
shinfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT | mask;
shinfo.hwnd = NULL;
shinfo.lpVerb = "open";
shinfo.lpFile = prog;
shinfo.lpParameters = NULL;
shinfo.lpDirectory = 0;
shinfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI;
shinfo.nShow = SW_SHOWDEFAULT;

rc = ShellExecuteEx(&shinfo);
```

[image]

Comment: What would you expect it to do instead? What behavior do you get in Explorer if you double-click a file with no extension? (In Win7, I get an "Open with" dialog, because there can't be a default application for an unknown type of file, and if I select an app like Notepad it won't let me assign it as the program to always use for this type of file.)

Comment: With 'open' verb, you should get an error 'ERROR_NO_ASSOCIATION'. This is the behavior you see in platforms less than windows 8. Try it out yourself running the code and let me know your observation.

Comment: I just did a quick test (Delphi, not C++). Once I corrected the mask to a single `SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI or SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT`, running it on Win7 returns false, and GetLastError() shows `ERROR_NO_ASSOCIATION`. However, changing `lpVerb` to NULL rather than 'open' displays the Open With dialog. I'd suspect that there is no default 'open' verb on Win8 for files with no extension. If you right-click a file with no extension in Explorer, what is the bolded (default) option at the top of the context menu?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect there is no default action associated with `open` on Windows 8 for files without an extension. I confirmed this using your code (a Delphi version of it, anyway) on Windows 7.

Running the code with `shinfo.lpverb` set to 'open' caused `ShellExecuteEx` to return `FALSE`, and `GetLastError` did indeed return `ERROR_NO_ASSOCIATION`. However, changing `lpVerb` to NULL (nil in Delphi) instead displayed the standard Win7 **Open With** dialog, just like your code does on Windows 8.

Here's a modified version of your code for testing:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO shinfo;
memset(&shinfo, 0, sizeof(shinfo));
shinfo.cbSize = sizeof(shinfo);
shinfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT | SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI;
shinfo.lpVerb = NULL;
shinfo.lpFile = prog;
shinfo.hwnd = NULL; 
shinfo.lpParameters = NULL;
shinfo.lpDirectory = 0;
shinfo.nShow = SW_SHOWDEFAULT;

rc = ShellExecuteEx(&shinfo);
```

Here's my test Delphi code for comparison (a quite literal translation of your C++ code):

```
var
  shInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;

  FillChar(shInfo, SizeOf(shInfo), 0);   // Same result as memset()
  shInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(shInfo);
  shInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI or SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT;
  shInfo.Wnd := 0;                       
  shInfo.lpVerb := nil;                  // Also tested with 'open'
  shInfo.lpDirectory := 'D:\TempFiles';  // Path to my no-extension file
  shInfo.lpFile := 'datafile';           // My test file with no ext
  shInfo.nShow := SW_SHOWDEFAULT;
  if not ShellExecuteEx(@shInfo) then
    ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)); // Readable error message
```

A quick change to your code to replace "open" with NULL as the `lpVerb` should confirm.

You can also confirm my suspicion fairly easily by right-clicking a file with no extension in Win8's Explorer, and checking the **bold** default action at the top of the context menu. If there is no bold option, or if it's anything but **open**, my suspicions are correct.

Comment: Thanks Ken for your experiment. I see the bold option in Win 8 as 'open with'. Do you know if there is a way to get the old behavior of getting the error? I don't see MSDN has any note about the change in behavior for Win 8. That surprise me a lot.

Comment: It shouldn't surprise you at all; there are many file types that have no default "open" option (which is why I had my suspicions about the cause). I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish in the first place, so I can't suggest a workaround. You haven't yet explained why you would be attempting to launch a file that has no extension. It seems to me it would be easier to check to see if the file has an extension before trying to launch it, and handle the missing extension appropriately first.

Comment: An example of other file types with no "open" verb: The recent Adobe Reader XI, which changes the default option to "Open with Adobe Reader XI", which causes ShellExecuteEx to fail with the "open" verb. I don't have a WIn8 machine available, so I can't help figure out how to get the behavior you're wanting.